# Using jQuery to make content from a link appear in specified div

Tags: html, jquery, hyperlink

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the content from a link appear in the 'mobileContent' div element using jQuery. I can't seem to find a solution that fits exactly. Here is the html, and thank you in advance:

```
  <body>
    <div class="containerDiv">
      <div class="mainDiv1Mobile">
        <div class="headerContainer">
          <div class="headerDesc">
            <a href="#">Email</a>,&nbsp;
            <a href="#>Instagram</a>
          </div>
          <div class="headerNav">
            ⇩ <a href="projectLinks.html" class="nav">Projects</a>
            ⇨ <a href="moreInfo.html" class="nav">More Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobileContent"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select `.mobileContent` and use the [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function to insert an `a` tag.

```js
$('.mobileContent').html(
  $('<a></a>').attr('href', 'https://www.google.com').text('Link to Google')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerDiv">
  <div class="mainDiv1Mobile">
    <div class="headerContainer">
      <div class="headerDesc">
        <a href="#">Email</a>,&nbsp;
        <a href="#">Instagram</a>
      </div>
      <div class="headerNav">
        ⇩ <a href="projectLinks.html" class="nav">Projects</a> ⇨ <a href="moreInfo.html" class="nav">More Info</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobileContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*N.B.* You have a misspelling (a missing `"` in the Instagram `a`).

Answer (score 1):

Call this on click of the element

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.websitetogetcontentfrom.com/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) { 
    
            $("#mobileContent").html(data);
    
        }
    });
```

Normal html pages over http:// load with this when called from another page on http://. However, you won't be able to load from localhost and there are many restrictions on such an operation and I doubt if sites like instagram allows you to this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure which link content you want displayed, but I'll do my best to help in some way :)

Please don't shoot if I am misunderstanding the question LOL.

But assuming you want to show the content of more info inside the div mobileContent based on clicking something in the nav bar, you could do something like this.

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav").click(function(){
    $("#mobileContent").show();
  });
});
```

html

```
<body>
<div class="containerDiv">
    <div class="mainDiv1Mobile">
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <div class="headerDesc">
        <a href="#">Email</a>,&nbsp;
        <a href="#>Instagram</a>
        </div>
        <div class="headerNav">
        ⇩ <a href="projectLinks.html" class="nav">Projects</a>
        ⇨ <a href="moreInfo.html" class="nav">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mobileContent" style="display: none;"></div>
        <a href="moreInfo.html" class="nav">More Info</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope that helps or helps you get to where you need to go.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your response. I am wanting the content from the links in the nav (projectLinks.html) to show up in  the mobileContent div when you click on them.

Comment: Cool so from the project links html page what element are you trying to bring in and can you show the html structure of that page?